# I need to output an HTML string but I get an error

Tags: javascript, html, telegram, telegram-bot

I need to display all users found by request. As I understand it, this can only be done in this way, but the problem is that I get an error that supposedly the message is empty.

```
User.find({Inviter: helpers.getUserID(query)})
    .then(inviters => {
    
        console.log(inviters)
    
        let html = inviters.map((f, i) => {
            return `${i+1}. ${f._id} `
        })
        console.log(html)
        
        bot.sendMessage(chatID, html, {
            parse_mode: "HTML"
        })
    
    })
```

Here is the error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: ETELEGRAM: 400 Bad Request: message text is empty
    at C:\Users\Basanas\Desktop\DeclBOT\node_modules\node-telegram-bot-api\src\telegram.js:299:15
    at tryCatcher (C:\Users\Basanas\Desktop\DeclBOT\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Users\Basanas\Desktop\DeclBOT\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:547:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Users\Basanas\Desktop\DeclBOT\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:604:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Users\Basanas\Desktop\DeclBOT\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:649:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Users\Basanas\Desktop\DeclBOT\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:729:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (C:\Users\Basanas\Desktop\DeclBOT\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:93:12)
    at _drainQueue (C:\Users\Basanas\Desktop\DeclBOT\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:86:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (C:\Users\Basanas\Desktop\DeclBOT\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:102:5)
    at Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (C:\Users\Basanas\Desktop\DeclBOT\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:15:14)
    at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:478:21)
```

I tried to change the method, but with others I can't get what I need.

Plain HTML works as it should. For example like this.

```
let html = `Your referals: <strong> bold <strong>
```

Comment: so does `console.log(html)` output anything????

Comment: Yes, it displays what I need

Comment: `html` is an array. Does `bot.sendMessage()` expect an array or a single string?

Comment: Try adding `.join('')` to the end of the assignment to `html`.

Comment: Yes thank you. Although I really guessed it myself) But your version is also good, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Should have changed that and added ' '

```
bot.sendMessage(chatID, `${html}`, {
                            parse_mode: "HTML"
                        })
```

The only thing is that I get the ',' sign, which I don't need, but I roughly understand how to remove it

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3p1s5.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).